# Send an email with attachments via the GMAIL api from a webpage

Tags: javascript, gmail, gmail-api

I'm trying to send an email with attachments via js from a webpage, with the Gmail api. I managed to log in, to send an email without attachments But I got an error when I try to add attachments. The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: files[i] is undefined
> onload http://localhost:8000/:189
> sendEmailWithAttachments http://localhost:8000/:182
>  debugger eval code:1
> Anyway files[i] is not undefined and I can see that from the console.log. The files attribute is from an input file element on the dom.

I tryed this

```
function sendEmailWithAttachments(to, subject, body, files) {
var message = new Object();
message.to = to;
message.subject = subject;
message.body = body;
var boundary = 'foo_bar_baz';
var multipart = '';
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
var reader = new FileReader();
console.log("il primo file è ",files[i].name)
reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
reader.onload = function () {
if(reader.result!=undefined){
var base64Data = reader.result.split(",")[1];
multipart += '--' + boundary + '\r\n' +
'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n' +
'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' +
'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' + files[i].name + '"\r\n\r\n' +
base64Data + '\r\n';} else{
console.log("reader.result contains: ",reader.result)
}
};
}
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
'userId': 'me',
'resource': {
'raw': window.btoa(
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" + boundary + "\"\r\n" +
"MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" +
"to: " + to + "\r\n" +
"subject: " + subject + "\r\n\r\n" +
"--" + boundary + "\r\n" +
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n" +
"MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" +
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n" +
body + "\r\n\r\n" +
multipart +
"--" + boundary + "--"
)
}
});
request.execute(function(response) {
console.log(response);
});
}
```

Comment: Maybe when you call the `sendEmailWithAttachments` your arguments are getting messed up somehow. Could you log the `files` argument to check what's being passed to the function? Please edit your question to include the result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

FileReader is run with the asynchronous process. I'm worried that the reason for your current issue might be due to this. In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
async function sendEmailWithAttachments(to, subject, body, files) {
  var message = new Object();
  message.to = to;
  message.subject = subject;
  message.body = body;
  var boundary = 'foo_bar_baz';
  var multipart = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    console.log("il primo file è ", files[i].name)
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      reader.onload = _ => resolve();
    });
    if (reader.result != undefined) {
      var base64Data = reader.result.split(",")[1];
      multipart += '--' + boundary + '\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n' +
        'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' +
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
        'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' + files[i].name + '"\r\n\r\n' +
        base64Data + '\r\n';
    } else {
      console.log("reader.result contains: ", reader.result)
    }
  }
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
    'userId': 'me',
    'resource': {
      'raw': window.btoa(
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" + boundary + "\"\r\n" +
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" +
        "to: " + to + "\r\n" +
        "subject: " + subject + "\r\n\r\n" +
        "--" + boundary + "\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n" +
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" +
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n" +
        body + "\r\n\r\n" +
        multipart +
        "--" + boundary + "--"
      )
    }
  });
  request.execute(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

- When the values of `gapi.client` and `to, subject, body, files` are valid values, I confirmed that this modified script worked.

#### Reference:

- [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)